# Getting a Compilation Error: Array3.java:13 error '.class' expected disp(arr1[]);

Tags: java, arrays

Code for taking an array as an input argument and give some values from keyboard and print it. Using method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Array3
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int [] arr1 = new int[3];
        disp(arr1[]);   //Here I'm getting the Compilation error
    }

    public static void disp(int arg[])
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the elements of array: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++)
        {
            arg[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("the elements is the array ar1[] are: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < arg.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(arg[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get

```
Array3.java:13: error: '.class' expected
                disp(arr1[]);
```

Comment: You're not supposed to include the `[]` when you pass the array as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an `array` as parameter of a method, only the name is required :

```
disp(arr1[]);  // wrong
disp(arr1);    // correct
```

---

Also, `sc` will be undefined in the scope of `disp()` because it's defined in the `main`, the better is to define the `Scanner` in the method that needs it :

```
 public static void disp(int arg[]) {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I corrected your comments, but it's more clear like this, IMHO